# Create round-robin sharding while generating sharded tfrecords

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, image-segmentation, sharding, tfrecord

I am new to tensorflow and I am working on image segmentation problem in tensorflow 1.14. I have a huge dataset and generating tfrecords is very slow, when I try to generate one big tfrecord file. So, I would like to create 'n' shards of tfrecords. I could not find a way to do it online. Say I have 600 images and 600 masks. I want to generate 6 shards of tfrecords, with 100 images and 100 masks each in round robin fashion. A high level /pseudo-code of what I want is as follows -

```
sharded_tf_record_writer:
create n TFRecordWriter
----> for each_item in n TFRecordWriter
      -----> write_example in round-robin fashion
```

I did search online and could not find relevant answer. I do not want to use apache beam for sharding. I appreciate any idea/help/guidance to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I had asked the same question in one of the issues of tensorflow datasets and the user - Conchylicultor responded this -

> Writing is done by _TFRecordWriter. Tfds will automatically compute the required number of shards and distribute examples across shards, However each shard is written sequentially.
>   You do not have control over the number of shards, it is also automatically computed.
>
> However, the fact that examples are distributed between shards do not make the writing faster as examples are not pre-processed in parallel. If you want parallelism, then you'll have to use Apache Beam which allow to scale even to huge datasets

The link to the tensorflow/datasets issue is - https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/issues/676

This might help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with object detection in tensorflow, there are some nice code in the official Tensorflow [models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) repository that will do what you want. Note this code is for Tensorflow2 (not sure if it'll work in TF1)

See this [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/3dacd474364813781c0154d881055502ce09d79c/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_coco_tf_record.py#L362) of writing sharded tfrecords from coco annotations. The idea is that you open up a list of TFRecordWriter in an exit stack (using `contextlib2.ExitStack()`), which will automatically close the TFRecords when each thread finishes writing to it.

The utility function [open_sharded_output_tfrecords](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/tf_record_creation_util.py) function creates this list of TFRecordWriter

```
import contextlib2
import tensorflow as tf
with contextlib2.ExitStack() as tf_record_close_stack, tf.gfile.GFile(
    annotations_file, 'r'
) as fid:
    output_tfrecords = tf_record_creation_util.open_sharded_output_tfrecords(
        tf_record_close_stack, output_path, num_shards
    )
```

Next you can use the ProcessPoolExecutor to write tfrecords into each shard in a round-robin fashion in parallel (4 workers in this example)

```
from concurrent.futures.process import ProcesPoolExecutor
with ProcessPoolExecutor(4) as executor:
    for idx, image in enumerate(images):
        futures = []
        future = executor.submit(
            _write_tf_record,
            image,
            idx,
            num_shards,
            output_tfrecords,
        )
        futures.append(future)
    for future in futures:
        future.result()
```

where `_write_tf_record` may look something like this:

```
def _write_tf_record(image, idx, num_shards, output_tfrecords)
    tf_example = create_tf_example(image)
    shard_idx = idx % num_shards
    output_tfrecords[shard_idx].write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
```

Just make sure you have more shards than multiprocess workers, otherwise the same writer may be accessed by two different processes.